# Use except() to exclude items from List

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core

Trying to use Except to exclude items from a list. However the following code is not working for me i.e. my list still includes the records that it should exclude. Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong? Is there an issue with my loops? BTW the inverse of this code works i.e correct record is inserted when RunTime matches.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult InsertActivities([FromBody] List<MemberData> customers)
        {
            var mData =_context.MemberData.Select(x => x.RunTime).ToList();
            foreach (var item in mData)
            {
                var exclude = customers.Where(x => x.RunTime == item).ToList();
                var list = customers.Except(exclude).ToList();

                foreach (var data in list)
                {
                    _context.MemberData.Add(data);
                }
            }
            int insertedRecords = _context.SaveChanges();
            return Json(insertedRecords);
        }
```

Comment: Does `MemberData` override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?

Comment: I think `var exclude = customers.Where(x => x.RunTime == item).ToList();` needs to be a IEnumerable instead of list. Can you try: `var list = customers.Except(customers.Where(x => x.RunTime == item).ToList()`

Comment: Thanks @osfresia but unfortunately the above didn't work, still inserting all records from customers rather than customers minus the except condition

Comment: Did you checked if the "exclude" returns the values you want to exclude?

Comment: @osfresia "IEnumerable instead of list."???? That is one very confusing comment - no idea what you mean there...

Comment: This seem to be usual case of using (x != "A" || x != "B" || x != "C") for "x is neither "A,B,C". Some [MRE} that just use lists (instead of DB operations) may help to clarify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly be sure you have model design like below:

```
public class MemberData:IEquatable<MemberData>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RunTime { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MemberData other)
    {
        if (other is null)
            return false;

        return this.RunTime == other.RunTime;
    }
    public override bool Equals(object obj) => Equals(obj as MemberData);
    public override int GetHashCode() => (RunTime).GetHashCode();
}
```

Then change your code like below:

```
public JsonResult InsertActivities([FromBody] List<MemberData> customers)
{
    //hard-coded the value...
    //customers = new List<MemberData>()
    //{
    //    new MemberData(){RunTime="aa"},
    //    new MemberData(){RunTime="bb"},
    //    new MemberData(){RunTime="ee"},
    //};   //hard-coded the value...
    var mData = _context.MemberData.ToList();
    var list = customers.Except(mData);
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        foreach (var data in list)
        {
            _context.MemberData.Add(data);
        }
    }
    int insertedRecords = _context.SaveChanges();
    return Json(insertedRecords);
}
```

**Note:**

For inserting data to database successfully, if your model contains primary key, be sure the data's(`after did` Except `operation`) keys are not duplicated with the existing database data. Or you can just do like what I did in above code that do not set value for primary key.

Comment: Thank you so much for this detailed example @Rena. I was completely lost. You've saved the day! Cheers